# consulta Mysql con datos enviados por POST

Tags: php, mysql, post

estoy completando un DataTable con una consulta a mi base de datos
tengo un formulario donde ingreso la fecha y presiono el botón buscar y envió el dato pero mi consulta no se realiza con el dato que llega por post si ingreso el mismo dato manual en la consulta funciona.

aquí llega el dato por post hice un var_dump y el dato llega correcto.
mi base de datos el campo fecha esta configurado como varchar.

```
<?php 
include ("funciones/bd_conec.php");

$fecha = $_POST['fechaid'];
$folio = $_POST['folio'];

//$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE NumAla NOT LIKE '0'";
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE NunAla = 638";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE Fecha = '12-03-2019'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE Fecha = $fecha"; // NO FUNCIONA ENVIO LA MISMA FECHA (12-03-2019)
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if( !$resultado ){
    die("Error");
}else{
    while ( $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $arreglo["data"][] = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);
    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);


}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqly_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Comment: Intentaste agregando comillas simples?

Comment: Si le e intentado de muchas formas con las comillas y nada. al hacer la consulta asi: $sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE Fecha = $fecha"; la consulta no da error pero devuelve null

Comment: puedes poner un `var_dump($fecha);exit();` antes de ejecutar tu consulta para ver que lleva la variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El fallo lo tienes aquí:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE Fecha = $fecha";
```

Prueba con esto y me dices:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE Fecha = '$fecha'";
```

Comment: Perdona @alanfcm, acabo de responderle lo mismo que le habías sugerido tú

Answer (score 0):

intenta con comillas simples pero concatenandolo como cadena php

elemplo consulta  :
[sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datos WHERE Fecha = '".$fecha."'";
```